# Look up table using large raster (in R)

Tags: r, function, spatial, r-raster, bigdata

Really hope you can help me out. Thank you in advance, for everything I've learned from these pages up to this point. And apologies, my know-how is limited by the part-time nature at which i'm attempting to learn all there is in R.

My Aim:
Look up table inversion using (large) rasters.

What I have at the moment:

```
#Observed data (in this case just as a dataframe)
obs <- data.frame(runif(100,0,1))

#Two sets of simulated data (often n >10 000)
sim.A <- data.frame(runif(1000,0,1))

sim.B <- data.frame(runif(1000,0,1))

#Calculate the error [cost] for each observed value and every simulated(A) value
error.fun <- function(x){sqrt((x-sim.A)^2)}              
error <- apply(obs,1,error.fun) 

#Find the position of the min [error] value
min.func <- function(x){which(x == min(x),arr.ind = F)}    
cost.min <- apply(error,2,min.func)

#Subset the simulated (B) dataset at the position of the least error[cost.min]
LUT.values = data.frame(sim.B[cost.min,])
```

My Problem(s):

1) The code above works for samples extracted from the raster. But, I need to replace sampled observations with an entire (ncell > 1Mil) raster. I obviously need to optimize the above two functions (into one?), but the closest I've got leaves me skeptical as the results are poor compared to the sampled data attempts.

My Attempt for large rasters:

```
#This runs, but I dont think it's working correctly

crs.UTM <- CRS("+proj=utm +zone=36 +south +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs+ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0")
r <- raster( crs=crs.UTM)
extent(r) <- extent(0, 100, 0, 100) 
res(r) <- c(1, 1)
values(r) <- runif(ncell(r), 0, 1)

#Simulated data (often n >10 000)
sim.A <- data.frame(runif(1000,0,1))

sim.B <- data.frame(runif(1000,0,1))

cost.min.func <- function(x){
cost <- sqrt((x-sim.A)^2)     
c.min <- sim.B[which(cost == min(cost),arr.ind = FALSE),]}

LUT.rst <- calc(r,cost.min.func)
```

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are after

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(ext=extent(0, 100, 0, 100), res=1, crs="+proj=utm +zone=36 +south +datum=WGS84 +units=m")

set.seed(0)
values(r) <- runif(ncell(r), 0, 1)

sim.A <- runif(1000,0,1)
sim.B <- runif(1000,0,1)

cost <- function(x) {
  y <- abs(x-sim.A)
  sim.B[which.min(y)]
}
x <- calc(r, cost)
```

This will take a while on a large data set. It should be possible to first approximate this by using a range of values for x and then perhaps only consider computing this for a few cells that might have the min value

Comment: Thank you Robert. This is perfect, and much much quicker. My low accuracies persist, but I'll keep digging into that (ill-posed problem etc). Thanks for this solution though.

Answer (score 0):

what you are missing is the average of `observed - simulated`:

```
rmse <- sqrt(mean((obs-sim)^2))
```